# How can I add a word before your domain name on a website?

Tags: python, django, url, dns

I don't know if this is relevant, but I am using Django to build a website.

How do you add a word before your domain name? For example, with locations: *location.website.com*, similar to how [Craigslist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craigslist) has a different URL for every city. How do you do this?

Comment: Have a look at DNS --- domain name systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain) and has nothing to do with Django. It's like a mini website within your main website.

More information is [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032285/how-to-create-a-subdomain-and-how-do-they-work).

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why people are downvoting me...I just didn't know what it was called, and didn't know how else to find out!

Comment: @user2676680 I think the downvotes are from 'rich' purists who want to uphold question quality. Don't mind them :) And make sure to mark answers as accepted if you have found your answer to close the question.