# What are these kind of web links called: 'docs.soliditylang.org'?

Tags: html, node.js

I know how to create something like `http://www.website-name.com/xyz`, but I wish to create a link, like `http://www.xyz.website-name.com`. I have been searching for this for sometime now, and unable to find any answer. Can someone please help, as I am new to web development?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something called - subdomain. Maybe this would help: [Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032285/how-to-create-a-subdomain-and-how-do-they-work#:%7E:text=A%20subdomain%20simply%20means%20that,the%20foo%20dns%20server%20layer.)