# How to include a string in my website url?

Tags: javascript, html, web, url

I created a shop and the url is like:
https://myshop.com

But my client asked me to add respective salers' id into the url so that they can do some analyses, so it would look like:
https://saler001.myshop.com

I don't know where should I start to do this trick, maybe something in the DNS settings? Currently I've suggested them using url query string, but they don't accept.

btw, this shop is on Shopify.

Comment: So what are you trying to do with JS?

Comment: I probably would get the saler's id from url and add it into my order's custom field.

Comment: You want to use JS to retrieve the saler's id from the URL?

Comment: Is it not doable? I'm not even trying so maybe this is another problem.

Comment: Client-side JavaScript has nothing to do with this. You need a catch-all subdomain for your domain, and then server-side, you can check the URL to see which seller's shop is requested every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the URL with the [`URL` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL), get the host name, then split it by a comma to get the subdomain.

```js
const url = "https://saler001.myshop.com" //URL can be retrieved via `document.URL`

const id = new URL(url).hostname.split('.')[0].substr(5)
console.log(id)
```

Comment: thanks for this method, but could you shed some light on the previous step? I'm not sure how to achieve this by DNS.

Comment: @user3602859 I would suggest checking [How to create a subdomain and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032285/how-to-create-a-subdomain-and-how-do-they-work) or asking another question if the problem you're encountering is specific. Posts should only be limited to 1 question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Nginx, I think change vhost file can do it. (Apache also can do)

like there:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<name>\w+)\.myurl\.com$;

    location /admin {
        return 301 $scheme://www.myurl.com/sub=$name;
    }
}
```

---

If you can't change "HTTP proxy server", MUST check subdomain not work. if not work (find any subdomain will goto "www" your site), use @Spectric answer is right.

otherwise the "sub.google.com" only goto "sub.google.com" site, and not "www.google.com" / "google.com" site.

in there, you must use "Server API" check from site and do shop work, use like PHP or GoLange, etc.